# Access file processed by a module in DocAssemble interview

Tags: docassemble

I've written a python module which generates an image from a bunch of values as plot. The module uses matplotlib and pandas for the generation of the image. Now I'm a bit in trouble accessing the image from inside DocAssemble to put the image into a docx template. Therefore I've some questions:

1. The image will be saved within the module in `/usr/share/docassemble/files/image.png`. I don't think that this is the proper path to save files in DA. Where can I save such files to be accessed in the later interview?

```
plt.savefig("/usr/share/docassemble/files/image.png")
```

2. What is the right way to implement the image from such a path into a docx document using DA YAML?

*extract from da yml file*

```
---
modules:
  - .plot_file
[...]
---
code: |
 plot_file(datapoints)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize a `DAFile` object in your YAML and then pass that object to your `plot_file()` function.  Your `plot_file()` function can write data to the path indicated by `.path()` and then run `.commit()`. This will ensure that your code works properly even if the server keeps its files on S3.

```
modules:
  - .plot_file
---
objects:
  - myfile: DAFile
---
code: |
  plot_file(datapoints, myfile)
```

Then in your module you could do something like:

```
def plot_file(datapoints, the_file):
  the_file.initialize(filename="plot.png")
  ...
  with open(the_file.path(), 'rb') as file_pointer:
    file_pointer.write(data)
  the_file.commit()
```

See the first example in [this section](https://docassemble.org/docs/objects.html#DAFile) for an example.

Docassemble is designed to be a cloud-based application, so you can't assume that the machine that processes a request at time 1 will be the same machine that processes a request at time 2. That is why files are abstracted as `DAFile` objects; the `DAFile` code takes care of storing the file on S3 and retrieving it from S3. The `DAFile` class also provides a permissions system so that other users on the server can't access your file unless you have specifically called `.set_attributes()` or `.user_access()` in order to grant permission.